# C++: ignore a declaration

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am using C++ preprocessor macros to selectively ignore some code blocks for testing purposes, e.g.

```
#ifdef __SAFE
    #define note 
    #define ensure(X) if(X) {} else 
#else
    #define note while(false)
    #define ensure(X) while(false)
#endif
```

Intuitively, `note` executes some code (usually setting some guard variable) and `ensure` executes the next code block if the condition is violated. With these macros, I can write:

```
note { var = true }
ensure(var == true) { throw new std::exception; }
```

and the code will compile whether `__SAFE` is defined or not (and the compiler will most likely get rid of the dummied out code). This is nice because it behaves essentially as an extension of the C++ language.

I would also like to similarly skip some data member declarations in classes when `__SAFE` is undefined. The tricks above do not work anymore, since flow control is disallowed inside a class declaration. I would like to declare some macro `guard` for which the class:

```
class A {
guard int x;
}
```

contains member `int x` only when `__SAFE` is defined.

Possible solutions:

- Some precompiler tricks are able to replace `guard` by `//`, thus obtaining the desired result; but they only work in some compilers (in particular, not in `g++`). Also, it seems that comment removal takes place before preprocessing, so it probably won't work anyway.
- Surround the declaration with an `#ifdef ... #endif` block. It works, but it is somewhat verbose.
- Define `guard(X)` as `X` if `__SAFE` is defined, and as a blank space otherwise. This works too, but it would be great to get rid of the parentheses, and simply grab the argument as "everything until the next semicolon".

I know the C++ preprocesor is not very powerful. I would just like to know if there is an aesthetically pleasant solution; otherwise I will simply use  the latter option.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__SAFE`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, @PeteBecker !

Comment: I think you should add `#ifdef __SAFE ... #else ...#endif` everywhere you want it to apply. This way your code will be more readable and less error prone. For example inside the class: `#ifdef __SAFE [newline] int x; [newline] #endif`

Comment: @Killzone Kid He did say he thought it was verbose. It's all a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: @Zebrafish I would call it explicit instead of verbose, but yeah, it is a matter of preference

Comment: I remember spending ages trying to figure out a preprocessor trick where I wouldn't have to constantly redefine static class members in a cpp separate from the .h class definition. I so hate that requirement.

Comment: I would recommend you to avoid some code... It makes the code harder to understand for one that does not know your code. As much as possible, you should try to use specific functions or macros for specific DEBUG code. That way, you can more easily select which debugging code you want to execute. Most debugging code should be assertion anyways.

Comment: @underscore_d -- Re: "No?" No. "Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation **for any use**." [global.names]/1 (emphasis added).

Comment: @PeteBecker Right, my bad. The restriction that only applies to the global namespace is **any** identifier beginning with an `_`, followed by anything (not just an upper-case letter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11, you can use a template alias, something like:

```
struct A {
  guarded<int> x;
};
```

where `guarded` is defined as:

```
#ifdef YOUR_SAFE_MACRO

template<typename T>
using guarded_impl = T;

#define guarded guarded_impl

#else

template<typename T>
struct guarded_impl {};

#define guarded static guarded_impl

#endif
```

this has also the bonus of giving a linker error if the variable is ODR-used when `YOUR_SAFE_MACRO` is off (if on, the dummy static variable is still there, but should be optimized out at link time if unused).

You can do this in < C++11 as well, but it will be slightly more verbose.

That said, I guess *note*, *ensure* and *guard* are too common names to be used as macros and still hope no name clashing will occur, so I'd strongly advise against such a thing ( you've been warned :) )

Moreover, people reading your code will get confused by having a `static` hidden in a macro that looks like a template ... a good'ol `#ifdef` would be a better solution in my opinion.

Comment: Awesome. Hadn't thought about this use of template aliases. Thanks!